# Nested form not rendering Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The nested form in the view just won't render, unless I remove the f attribute, in which case the submit button will not work. I have two models, job and employer. I've been following the railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

**job.rb**

```
  attr_accessible :title, :location, :employers_attributes,     
  belongs_to :employers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employers
```

**employer.rb**

```
 attr_accessible :companyname, :url
 has_many :jobs
```

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
  def new

    @job = Job.new
    @employer = Employer.new
  end
```

**_form.html**

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>


    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>


    <%= f.label :location %>
    <%= f.text_field :location %>



  <%= f.fields_for :employers do |builder| %>

        <%= builder.label :companyname, "Company Name" %>
        <%= builder.text_field :companyname %>


        <%= builder.label :url, "Web Address" %>
        <%= builder.text_field :url %>

    <% end %>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

 <% end %>
```

Any input would be brilliant - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your job has no employers.

Change your code to this:

```
def new
  @job = Job.new
  @job.employer = @job.build_employer
end
```

In your job.rb change:

```
attr_accessible :title, :location, :employer_attributes,     
belongs_to :employer
accepts_nested_attributes_for :employer
```

Comment: It now throws a undefined method `employers' for nil:NilClass when viewing jobs/new

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's now throwing undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Why do you have it declared as `belongs_to` and not `has_many`. Jobs has one or many employers?

Comment: After updating the fields_for symbol, it works! thank you. Could you kindly explain the job.employer = job.build_employer line?

Comment: This line just creates a new Employer and assigns the @job to its jobs field (through the association). Read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
belongs_to :employers
```

Should be singulars:

```
belongs_to :employer
```

With this association you not need nested form you can use select for pick employer for each job.

But if you need many employers for each job and each job can have many employers see this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)